# Check SolrConnection in Java

Tags: apache, solr, aem

How can I check the connection of my ApacheSolrServer (HttpSolrServer) with java?

I've already tried:

```
if(server == null){
```

But this doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the actual connection between your CQ5 box and Solr instance you need to create SolrServer and call ping()

You can use the official SolrJ API, invoke http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer.html#ping%28%29

```
/**
* Issues a ping request to check if the server is alive
* @throws IOException If there is a low-level I/O error.
*/
public SolrPingResponse ping() throws SolrServerException, IOException {
 return new SolrPing().process( this );
}
```